# In ObjC, how to describe balance between alloc/copy/retain and auto-/release, in terms of location

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

As is common knowledge, calls to alloc/copy/retain in Objective-C imply ownership and need to be balanced by a call to autorelease/release. How do you succinctly describe where this should happen? The word "succinct" is key. I can usually use intuition to guide me, but would like an explicit principle in case intuition fails and that can be use in discussions.

Properties simplify the matter (the rule is auto-/release happens in `-dealloc` and setters), but sometimes properties aren't a viable option (e.g. not everyone uses ObjC 2.0).

Sometimes the release should be in the same block. Other times the alloc/copy/retain happens in one method, which has a corresponding method where the release should occur (e.g. `-init`  and `-dealloc`). It's this pairing of methods (where a method may be paired with itself) that seems to be key, but how can that be put into words? Also, what cases does the method-pairing notion miss? It doesn't seem to cover where you release properties, as setters are self-paired and `-dealloc` releases objects that aren't alloc/copy/retained in `-init`.

It feels like the object model is involved with my difficulty. There doesn't seem to be an element of the model that I can attach retain/release pairing to. Methods transform objects from valid state to valid state and send messages to other objects. The only natural pairings I see are object creation/destruction and method enter/exit.

Background:
This question was inspired by: "[NSMutableDictionary does not get added into NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573520/nsmutabledictionary-does-not-get-added-into-nsmutablearray)". The asker of that question was releasing objects, but in such a way that might cause memory leaks. The alloc/copy/retain calls were generally balanced by releases, but in such a way that could cause memory leaks. The class was a delegate; some members were created in a delegate method (`-parser:didStartElement:...`) and released in `-dealloc` rather than in the corresponding (`-parser:didEndElement:...`) method. In this instance, properties seemed a good solution, but the question still remained of how to handle releasing when properties weren't involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Properties simplify the matter (the rule is auto-/release happens in -dealloc and setters), but sometimes properties aren't a viable option (e.g. not everyone uses ObjC 2.0).

This is a misunderstanding of the history of properties. While properties are new, *accessors* have always been a key part of ObjC. Properties just made it easier to write accessors. If you always use accessors, and you should, than most of these questions go away.

Before we had properties, we used Xcode's built-in accessor-writer (in the Script>Code menu), or with useful tools like [Accessorizer](http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/accessorizer.html) to simplify the job (Accessorizer still simplifies property code). Or we just typed a lot of getters and setters by hand.

Comment: True, properties mostly add support at the language level for a common pattern. Now that I think of it, I usually use accessors when working with members in non-2.0 code. Plus, accessors are more aligned with the object model. Do accessors, combined with matching releases to retains within the same block, cover every case? That is, the rule is 1) auto-/release members in setters and `-dealloc` and 2) auto/-release local variables in the same block they're retained.

Comment: Properties mean that many, many people are no longer writing bad accessor methods.  That is a major plus.

Comment: @outis: These patterns should address every properly written case. The Analyze tools in Xcode 3.2 nicely check for this.

Answer (score 3):

The question isn't *where* it should happen, it's *when*.

Release or autorelease an object if you have created it with +alloc, +new or -copy, or if you have sent it a -retain message.

Send -release when you don't care if the object continues to exist.  Send -autorelease if you want to return it from the method you're in, but you don't care what happens to it after that.

Comment: I've been using "where" because I hope for the rule to identify the points in the source code (which is a matter of "where") to put releases. "When" is in terms of processes, which points out I've been thinking of programs when I should perhaps be thinking of processes.

Comment: The second paragraph is just a restatement of basic ownership rule (also stated in the first sentence of my question), but I like where the third is going. It needs something about releasing aggressively, *as soon as* you don't care.

Comment: One slight extension I would offer to the third sentence is that you set your reference to nil if you you are sending release and not only don't care if it continues to exist, but expect never to see it again.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say that `dealloc` is where you would call `autorelease`.  And unless your object, whatever it may be, is linked to the life of a class, it doesn't necessarily need to be kept around for a `retain` in `dealloc`.

Here are my rules of thumb.  You may do things in other ways.

- I use `release` if the life of the
  object I am using is limited to the
  routine I am in now.  Thus the object
  gets created and released in that
  routine.  This is also the preferred
  way if I am creating a lot of objects
  in a routine, such as in a loop, and
  I might want to `release` each object
  before the next one is created in the
  loop.
- If the object I created in a method
  needs to be passed back to the
  caller, but I assume that the use of
  the object will be transient and
  limited to this run of the runloop, I
  use `autorelease`.  Here, I am trying to mimic many of Apple's convenience routines.  (Want a quick string to use for a short period?  Here you go, don't worry about owning it and it will get disposed appropriately.)
- If I believe the object is to be kept
  on a semi-permanent basis (like
  longer than this run of the runloop),
  I use create/new/copy in my method
  name so the caller knows that they
  are the owner of the object and will
  have to `release` the object.
- Any objects that are created by a
  class and kept as a property with
  `retain` (whether through the property
  declaration or not), I `release` those
  in `dealloc` (or in `viewDidUnload` as
  appropriate).

Try not to let all this memory management overwhelm you.  It is a lot easier than it sounds, and looking at a bunch of Apple's samples, and writing your own (and suffering bugs) will make you understand it better.

Comment: auto-/release refers to whichever of `autorelease` or `release` is appropriate in a given context. For `-dealloc`, it refers to `release`.

Comment: @outis not necessarily.  It is not incorrect to `autorelease` in a `dealloc` method.  It's just (usually) smarter to `release` in `dealloc`.  `autorelease` is just for saying "I don't care about this object anymore, but someone else might want it soon, so I'll give them a chance to grab it by delaying the release for a bit."

Comment: It's not overwhelming. I have no difficulty with the notion of retain count memory management, nor with putting it into practice. I could even describe it in a couple paragraphs. The problem is succinctly describing where to release, which I feel is possible. "When" is easy: auto-/release if and only if you alloc/copy/retain. It's more a matter of pedagogy and discussion than anything.

Comment: @Dave DeLong: Granted, but my statement about context still holds. My comment was in response to mahboudz's first sentence.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I went and counted the `release` s in one of my iPhone projects: 111 total (`release` and `autorelease`) with 57 of them in my various `dealloc` s.

Comment: Actually, that should be "who" is easy. "auto-/release if and only if you alloc/copy/retain" is a matter of "who."

Comment: @mahboudz: how about setters? Other methods? Outside of `-dealloc` and setters, are any of the released objects not stored in local variables? The answers to this are relevant to the question I ask in the first comment to Rob Napier's answer.

Comment: Of course, if I am not interested in an object for more than the duration of my routine, I will be storing that object in a local variable, and releasing that object before the scope of the variable ends, and the object leaks. I think it is a mistake to try to tidily wrap it up in a rule like: "You only auto-/release in dealloc or setters. Or if it is a local variable. Or if you already released in viewDidUnload. Or in didReceiveMemoryWarning. Or when creating children objects fail, and you need to release the parent object so that you don't have a half-created object around. Or..."

Comment: @mahboudz: I've seen code that releases objects in clearly the wrong place/at the wrong time. There should be a simple principle that codifies this. Do you assert that no such principle can apply to every case?